# python project structure: folder naming convention

Tags: python, naming-conventions, project-management, pep8

I'm trying to rearrange my project files.
I'm having some hard time figuring out what is the correct way to name files and folders. I'm relying on [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#id37). I see that I should avoid having underscores in file/folder name. But if I have a folder like **functionalcoverage** it seems weird and feels like I should call it **functional_coverage** instead and the same goes for files(**securecopy**.py and **secure_copy**.py).
In addition, I'm not sure if I should  adhere to PEP8 regarding folders/files that aren't python(a folder containing a bunch of txt files for example)

Comment: PEP 8 is a guideline. You are free to follow it or not. In general following it will make things easier but as the PEP 8 itself points out: you project requirements should have precedence over the PEP rules. So if you have a **specific** question about a rule, please ask. If you just want to hear some opinions on the rules there, then sorry but SO is not the right place for it.

Comment: It's more important that your project is internally consistent than that parts of it are consistent with PEP 8.  Files (modules) should have underscores to improve readability.   You could adopt a more nested structure (if it would make sense for your project), and have `coverage.functional` instead of `functional_coverage`

Answer (score 2):

Its prety much what you prefer, a lot of people use underscore, PEP8 is a guide you can follow or not, the important is to be consistant with your choice read more [here](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#a-foolish-consistency-is-the-hobgoblin-of-little-minds)